# Change of measure for continuous distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $L$ denote the R.V. such that $L(X)=\log\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}$ where $X$ is ditributed according to $P$.

In the discrete case we have:
$$E_P(e^{-L(X)}) = \sum_{w}P(x)e^{-L(x)} = \sum_{w}P(x)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=1$$
where $E_P$ denote the expectation with respect to $P$.

Let assume that $L(X)$ has CDF $Q(z)$ and density $q(z)$, i.e. $q(z)=Q'(z)$. 
What is the equivalent of the above? i.e.

$E_P(e^{-L(X)}) = \int q(z)e^{-z}$ but this integral is not 1 in general.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure so that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty Q(x)dx = 1.$$

Then, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_P e^{-L(X)} & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)e^{-L(x)}dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty Q(x)dx = 1~.
\end{align}

For general spaces, we must define $$L(X) = \log \frac{\frac{dP}{dR}(X)}{\frac{dQ}{dR}(X)},$$ where $R$ is some probability measure such that $P\ll R$ and $Q\ll R,$ i.e. both $P$ and $Q$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $R$ and the same identity holds as long as $Q\ll P.$ It does NOT hold without this condition.

References: 
[Radon–Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative)
and
[Absolute continuity of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I see what you wrote. The thing is that you have used both $P(x)$ and $L(x)$. Suppose I have only the distribution of $L(X)$, and soppose that we have $Q<<P$ with density $q(z)$. What can be said about the density of $L(X)$ when $X$ is distribute according to $Q$? i.e. can we recover it from the density of $L(X)$ with respect to $P$?

Comment: Yes. If $L(X)$ has density $u(z)$ when $X$ is distributed as $P,$ then $L(X)$ has density $v(z)$ when $X$ is distributed as $Q$ with $v(z) = e^{-L(z)}u(z).$

Comment: The thing is that the density of P and Q is on the measuable space they defined on. However, L(x) is a real R. V. and the density is on the real axis